# Schwarz' theorem for real and imaginary part of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ open, $f:U\to\mathbb{C}$ has continuous second partial derivatives in $U$, then Schwarz' theorem states that in U it is $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\, \partial y}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\, \partial x}.$$
Let $\Re(f)$ the real part of $f$, $\Im(f)$ the imaginary part of $f$, is $\frac{\partial^2 \Re(f)}{\partial x\, \partial y}=\frac{\partial^2 \Re(f)}{\partial y\, \partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 \Im(f)}{\partial x\, \partial y}=\frac{\partial^2 \Im(f)}{\partial y\, \partial x}$? I think this could fail because $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ are only $\mathbb{R}$-linear, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The partial derivatives are $\mathbb{C}$-linear.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, actually the Schwarz' theorem is about real functions, the complex version is obtained from the real version by looking at real and imaginary parts.

**Schwarz' theorem** If $f : U \subset \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ has continuous partial derivatives, where $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ is open, then at every point $a \in U$ we have for all $i,j$
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\, \partial x_j}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j\, \partial x_i}.
$$